# More than 2 levels of population with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use mongoose populate for ability to return one composite document. Categories and questions are expanded fine. Answers array in questions is not expanded. Here's what I have been doing

```
summarySchema.statics.loadFull = function(options, callback){
    var self = this;
    self.findOne(options).populate([{
        path: 'categories'
    }])
    .exec(function(err, res){
        if(err || !res) return callback(err, res);
        self.populate(res, [{
            path: 'categories.questions',
            model: 'Question'
        }], function(err, res){
            if(err || !res || !res.length) return callback(err, res);
            self.populate(res, [{
                path : 'categories.questions.answers',
                model: 'Answer'
            }], function(err, res){
                callback(err, res);
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Is there an obvious mistake I am making or mongoose does not support more than 2 levels of population.

FYI, the structure is like

```
summary {categories : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'}]}
category {questions : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question'}]}
question {answers : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Answer'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was making a silly mistake that might not be obvious unless you see returned data. I should not be checking for length on an object that's not an array or string. I got the return values confused.  :)